# How to fix Ionic compile error after installing FirebaseX

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I've installed the FirebaseX plugin and since then I can't compile my project. It keeps crashing.
If I remove the plugin it compiles perfectly.

I've followed the documentation on Ionic's website and nothing. Help please

```
> cordova run ios
[cordova] ** BUILD FAILED **
[cordova]
[cordova]
[cordova] The following build commands failed:
[cordova]   PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Copy\ Pods\ Resources /Users/wd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-gftvmmnfqwbuwvcufrjakxcubeym/Build/Intermediates.noindex/myApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/myApp.build/Script-0B21D8ADE62B0FDBDC4B0B25.sh
[cordova] (1 failure)
[cordova] xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova run ios exited with exit code 65.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Here is my ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.9.0 (/Users/wd/.nvm/versions/node/v12.11.1/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.1.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.26
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, browser 6.0.0, ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.3, (and 17 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.14.0) : 0.8.1
   native-run (update available: 1.0.0)   : 0.3.0

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.10.0
   ios-sim    : 8.0.2
   NodeJS     : v12.11.1 (/Users/wd/.nvm/versions/node/v12.11.1/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.14.4
   OS         : macOS Catalina
   Xcode      : Xcode 11.4.1 Build version 11E503a
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer. So, I faced the same problem and the solution was:

```
ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-firebasex && ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex@latest-cli
```

After that do:

```
ionic cordova prepare ios --confirm --no-build
```

At the end try:

```
ionic cordova build ios
```

Hope it helps anyone who face this problem.